# Is there a method that can balance on two treatment?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

I am regressing an outcome on two treatments using differences in differences.

To deal with the pre-trend problem, I introduced some balancing method and run the regression separately on either treatment using the respective weights.

I am trying to add both treatments together and see whether they are orthogonal to each other.

Is there a method to balance on two treatments?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please clarify your definition of two treatments? Is it one treatment with two levels?

Comment: No they are two different treatments. For example if you change the corporation law, you can get treatments in reorganization and merger and acquisition etc.